# Excel VBA - Error Parsing Dates, Handling Strings

Tags: excel, vba, csv

The problem I have concerns a CSV file that I am seeking to parse into an excel spreadsheet.

An example of the data is as follows:-

```
01/02/2015,MXP,0.4,150.00,Producing design document, 64111258
02/06/2015,IHM,0.8,210.00,"Maximilian dolce, lorem ipsum", 64111258
02/06/2015,AXSP,0.6,250.00,"Magnificent, thanks very much", 64111258
```

Currently, this is the code I am using to parse the data:-

```
Sub OpenCSV()

    Dim filePath As String

    Dim intChoice As Integer 

    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False

    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

    rowIndex = 0

    If intChoice <> 0 Then  

        filePath = Application.FileDialog( _ msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1) 

        Open filePath For Input As #1

        Do Until EOF(1)

            Line Input #1, LineFromFile

            LineItem = Split(LineFromFile, ",")

            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(11, 2).Offset(rowIndex, 0).Value = LineItem(0) ' Date
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(11, 2).Offset(rowIndex, 1).Value = LineItem(1) ' Code
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(11, 2).Offset(rowIndex, 2).Value = LineItem(2) ' Hours
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(11, 2).Offset(rowIndex, 3).Value = LineItem(3) ' Cost
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(11, 2).Offset(rowIndex, 4).Value = LineItem(4) ' Description

            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1

        Loop

        Close #1

    End If

End Sub
```

The issues are as follows:-

1. Dates such as 02/06/2015 which are parsed and transposed to the excel cell will end up as 06/02/2015. This will not happen consistently, but happens randomly to various dates within the dataset.
2. CSV delimiter 4 will end up being parsed incorrectly where "" are in the data, as well as comma; Consequently the data is not transposed correctly to the relevant cell.

How can I go about correcting these errors?

Comment: If you import the CSV directly into Excel (no VBA) do you have the same issues? If you don't have problems, you might just try and record the macro and modify it to meet your needs. If that doesn't work, I could probably help with the second issue. But you'll really need to figure out when #1 happens to determine why it's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Dim arr() As String
  Dim newDate As Date

  arr = Split(LineItem(0), "/")
  newDate = DateSerial(Year:=arr(2), Month:=arr(1), Day:=arr(0))
```

Then use

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(11, 2).Offset(rowIndex, 0).Value = newDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim aData As Variant

    sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files, *.csv", MultiSelect:=False)
    If sFilePath = "False" Then Exit Sub    'Pressed cancel

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
        aData = .Sheets(1).Range("A1", .Sheets(1).Cells(.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).Value
        .Close False
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With wsDest.Range("B11").Resize(UBound(aData, 1), UBound(aData, 2))
        .Value = aData
        .Resize(, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"    'Can set date format here, change to dd/mm/yyyy if needed
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How do I apply logical operators to the data that is being copied? What if its non-linear, so I only want to copy certain cells rather than all cells between a1 and E for all rows. I'd rather iterate through the rows on a line by line basis. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the issue is a mismatch between the date format of your data and your Windows Regional Settings.  Several ways to handle this

- Change your Windows Regional Settings so they match
- Change the file type to a `*.txt` file.  Then use the `Workbooks.OpenText` method which allows you to specify the date column data type.
- Create a Data Connection which will also allow you to do the same.  Just be sure that you don't keep creating QueryTables.  It the table is already there, either delete and recreate, or refresh.

Here is some code demonstrating the QueryTable method.  In the Excel GUI this would be the Data ► Get External Data ► From text option

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenCSV()
Dim filePath As String
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim WS As Worksheet

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

If intChoice <> 0 Then

    filePath = Application.FileDialog( _
      msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

    Set WS = Worksheets("sheet2")
    With WS.QueryTables

    'If it exists, either delete and re-import or refresh
    If .Count > 0 Then
        Range(.Item(1).Destination.Address).CurrentRegion.Delete
        .Item(1).Delete
    End If
    End With
'
    With WS.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & filePath, Destination:=WS.Range("$B$11"))
        .Name = "New Text Document"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False

        'make sure format argument matches format in the csv file
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlDMYFormat)

        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

---